# How to verify Shopify webhook in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, shopify, webhooks

How can I verify the incoming webhook from Shopify? Shopify provides a [python implementation (of Flask)](https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/https#step-5-verify-the-webhook), but how can I do it in Django/DRF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set these two variables in the `settings.py` file

```py
# settings.py

SHOPIFY_HMAC_HEADER = "HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256"
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET = "5f6b6_my_secret"
```

Then, create a verify webhook function that accepts the Django request as it's parameter

```py
# utils.py

import base64
import hashlib
import hmac

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest


def verify_shopify_webhook(request: WSGIRequest):
    shopify_hmac_header = request.META.get(settings.SHOPIFY_HMAC_HEADER)
    encoded_secret = settings.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET.encode("utf-8")
    digest = hmac.new(
        encoded_secret,
        request.body,
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256,
    ).digest()
    computed_hmac = base64.b64encode(digest)
    return hmac.compare_digest(computed_hmac, shopify_hmac_header.encode("utf-8"))
```

Then, create a view that accepts the incoming webhook and use the `verify_shopify_webhook(...)` function to verify the request.

```py
# views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .utils import verify_shopify_webhook


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class ShopifyWebhookView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        verified = verify_shopify_webhook(request=request)
        return HttpResponse(status=200 if verified else 403)
```

If you're using [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you can also use **`APIView`** as

```py
# views.py

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .utils import verify_shopify_webhook


class ShopifyWebhookView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        verified = verify_shopify_webhook(request=request)
        return Response(status=200 if verified else 403)
```